# jQuery button fade on mouseenter and mouseleave doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Why won't this work, could it be the way I installed jquery onto the page?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#headerButton').mouseenter(function(){
                $('#headerButton').fadeTo('fast', 1);
            });
            $('#headerButton').mouseleave(function(){
                $('#headerButton').fadeTo('fast', 0.75);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: The double slash at the beginning of your `<script>` tag won't help.  Check your path.

Comment: @intracept That double slash means load this using the http/https protocol of the page, whichever is current.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I didn't know that :)  Learn something new every day!

Comment: Um. What's it meant to do? Without telling us, this question is 100% worthless. What goes wrong?

Comment: All code works... the question is what is it doing or not doing which you want it to do/not do.

Comment: when ever you hover over the button it's opacity is 1 and when you aren't hovering over it the opacity is .75, that is what it is meant to do

Comment: It is not changing opacity

Comment: You need to run it on a server to resolve the protocol, otherwise just add `http://` at the start

Comment: If setting the protocol doesn't work, then go to developer tools (F12 on most browsers) and view the console... if there's an error, you can go from there.  Otherwise we need to see more of the code.

Comment: If that's the solution, then, it's b/c you're running it locally.  If this script will be run in different environments, switch back to the `//` setting to avoid issues with SSL settings later on.

Comment: okay, so http:// won't work when hosted?

Comment: It will work fine, but just to let your server decide.

Comment: Yes, it will... if it is on a http:// connection.  But if it is hosted on a https:// connection and you have http:// put in there, then the browser will warn about unsecured content.  That's why for hosted settings, // is used when it could be either/or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript code is correct: the problem is on the jQuery src attribute.

Are you trying to run it from a web server or opening an html file on a browser?

If you are opening a file, the two slashes will mean:

```
   src="file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"
```

Because browsers use the "file:" protocol to open local files.
Which is probably the error.

Moreover, try to remove the spaces from:

```
   type = 'text/javascript'
```